# Where the right place to set layout in android?

Tags: android

I have 2 files in the res.
Activity_main.xml is

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test2.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_main.xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test2.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I plan to change the layout where I problem in this current layout when I drag and drop all item just overlap on each other how to make a nice form type layout? What adjustment and which file must I adjust?

Comment: How are you editing your layouts? Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: I am using eclipse and very new to android sorry for that.

Comment: No need to apologize. Can you be more clear about what you see that's overlapping? Also, are you using the GUI editor or are you editing the XML text directly?

Comment: I am trying the gui which one to is the correct one to load the element is the Activity_main.xml  or fragment_main.xml ? I think I know my mistake I was putting the elements on the activity_main.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the Eclipse GUI tools to create your layout. I strongly suggest that you read about [Android Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html). If you want, you can edit the XML layout text directly or at the very least this will help you understand the properties you can set for your controls to get the exact look that you want.

Comment: @user2711681 Most likely you should edit `fragment_main.xml`.

Comment: What does the activity_main does then? Why in that it shows as FrameLayout and the other file is relativelayout what difference does this makes?

Comment: @user2711681 The `FrameLayout` is a placeholder for the `Fragment`. In moderately comnplex apps, you will have more than one fragment for different screens in your app. You will replace the `FrameLayout` with the current fragment as the user navigates through your app. As my answer says, you should read about layouts (see the link in my answer). You should also read about fragments and how they work.

Comment: Thank you I will read through the link given and get a better idea. So for each screen I will have a different fragment_main.xml?

Comment: @user2711681 Exactly. And also a seprate XxxFragment.java file as well.

Comment: So how will the switch happen between this main screen and those xxxfragment.java?

Comment: @user2711681 Read [about Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for more details.